# Angular 2 overwrites url

Tags: angular

I have the following files structure:

```
--index.html
--app.html (Angular2 app)
```

Now, when I am navigating from landing page (index.hmtl) to app.html, browsers loads angular app. As soon as it is completed, my url changes from :

```
hostname/app.html

hostname/#/app
```

How can I make it not change the url , so that the path would be:

```
hostname/app.html#/app
```

or simply:

```
hostname/app.html/app
```

Here is my `boot.ts`

```
enableProdMode();
bootstrap(<any>AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this Angular doc about navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and CTRL+F for 'HashLocationStrategy'. You appear to be using the `HashLocationStrategy` as indicated above:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

This strategy adds the hash to your route. Look into adopting the `PathLocationStrategy`